Magento 2 : Pager not work in my custom collection
I have a custom collection for ordered products for a customer.
$connection = $this->resourceConnection->getConnection(\Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection::DEFAULT_CONNECTION);
    $customerSession = $this->customerSession->create();

    if ($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
        $customerId = $customerSession->getId();
        $result1 = $connection->fetchAll('SELECT distinct(product_id) FROM `sales_order_item` as soi INNER join sales_order as so on so.entity_id=soi.order_id WHERE so.customer_id = ' . $customerId);
        if (empty($result1)) {
            $this->messageManager->addWarningMessage(__("You don't have any product purchase yet."));

            $this->response->setRedirect('/customer/account/');
        }
    } else {
        $this->messageManager->addWarningMessage(__("Please login to see collection."));
        $this->response->setRedirect('/customer/account/login');
    }

    if (!empty($result1)) {
        $data = [];
        foreach ($result1 as $result) {
            $data[] = $result['product_id'];
        }
    }

    $collection1 = $this->productCollection->create();
    if (!empty($data)) {
        $collection1->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', ['in' => $data]);
        $collection1->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    }

    return $collection1;

I am calling this collection in my block class like below.
protected function _prepareLayout()
{
    $this->pageConfig->getTitle()->set(__(' Previously Bought Items'));
    parent::_prepareLayout();
    $page_size = $this->getPagerCount();
    $limit = ($this->getRequest()->getParam('limit')) ? $this->getRequest()->getParam('limit') : $this->getMinumRecord();
    $page_data = $this->getCustomData();
    if ($this->getCustomData()) {
        $pager = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
            \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager::class,
            'custom.custompager.name'
        )
            ->setAvailableLimit($page_size)
            ->setLimit($limit)
            ->setShowPerPage(true)
            ->setCollection($page_data);
        $this->setChild('pager', $pager);
        $this->getCustomData()->load();
    }
    return $this;
}

public function getCustomData()
{
    // get param values
    $page = ($this->getRequest()->getParam('p')) ? $this->getRequest()->getParam('p') : 1;
    $pageSize = ($this->getRequest()->getParam('limit')) ? $this->getRequest()->getParam('limit') : 1; // set minimum records
    // get custom collection
    $collection = $this->CustomCollection->getProductCollection();
    $collection->setPageSize($pageSize);
    $collection->setCurPage($page);
    return $collection;
}

public function getPagerCount()
{
    // get collection
    $minimum_show = 10; // set minimum records

    $page_array = [];
    $list_data = $this->bsLayer->getProductCollection();
    $list_count = ceil(count($list_data->getData()));
    $show_count = $minimum_show + 1;
    if (count($list_data->getData()) >= $show_count) {
        $list_count = $list_count / $minimum_show;
        $page_nu = $total = $minimum_show;
        $page_array[$minimum_show] = $minimum_show;
        for ($x = 0; $x <= $list_count; $x++) {
            $total = $total + $page_nu;
            $page_array[$total] = $total;
        }
    } else {
        $page_array[$minimum_show] = $minimum_show;
        $minimum_show = $minimum_show + $minimum_show;
        $page_array[$minimum_show] = $minimum_show;
    }
    return $page_array;
}

Here my page pagination and everything working fine except show per page filtering.
Do i miss something here?

Kinda struggled with the almost same issue last year...we still didn't came up with any solution on our side sadly, as soon as the collection printed is not directly linked with a catetegory and filters..it's becoming hell to handle :(
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/369648/update-layer-navigation-filter-with-the-proper-custom-collection

@Claims true, followed the all way to get the work done and not possible, so posted here too. In my case i am passing my filtered products to product collection and then passing the collection to block's _prepareLayout method
